# Solve system of equations using calculus & linear algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm having trouble with this problem. I'm not sure how to solve it the "calculus way". My professor gave us the formula "$b = c + Dt$" to work with (y = mx + b), and then dealt with partial derivatives. I'm not entirely sure how to start it though. Thanks.

> Find the best solution for the given system in two ways (a) using calculus (b) using linear algebra.
>
> $\left\{ 
> \begin{array}{c}
> x+2y=3 \\ 
> 3x+2y=5 \\
> x+y=2.09 \\
> \end{array}
> \right.$

Comment: We can find x=1 and y=1 from first two equations. But as you can see x=1 and y=1 not satisfy third equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the problem to be $$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
f_1=x+2y-3 \\ 
f_2=3x+2y-5 \\
f_3=x+y-2.09 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

and define $$\Phi=f_1^2+f_2^2+f_3^2$$ and say that you want this norm to be minimum.

So, compute the derivatives to get $$\Phi'_x=22x+18y-40.18$$  $$\Phi'_y=18x+18y-36.18$$ Set them equal to $0$. Solve for $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

Solving by Linear Algebra-

There is no solution to these equations. You write the coefficients of the equation and its right had side in as an augmented matrix and you do row reduction.
$$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&2&3\\
      3&2&5\\
      1&1&2.09
    \end{array}
\right]$$
Consider each row as `R1,R2,R3`. Now perform $${R2-3R1}$$
$$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&2&3\\
      0&-4&-4\\
      1&1&2.09
    \end{array}
\right]$$
$${-R2\over4}$$ 
$$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&2&3\\
      0&1&1\\
      1&1&2.09
    \end{array}
\right]$$
$${R3-R1}$$ 
$$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&2&3\\
      0&1&1\\
      0&-1&-0.91
    \end{array}
\right]$$

$${R3+R1}$$ 
$$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&2&3\\
      0&1&1\\
      0&0&0.09
    \end{array}
\right]$$

Last row `R3` denotes that `0=0.09`. So there is no solution for the equations.